# exec function blocks other requests during the execution

Tags: http, request, system, exec, response

I can't get http response when a *exec* or *system* function is excuting.

1. A specific request launch the *exec* function `sudo find / -name toto`, this take a while
2. During the execution, the client send any other requests
3. I don't get responses

Did you have a similar problem ? I tried shell_exec, exec, system...

I tried also this case :
A request launch a infinite loop
A second request launch an other script who return 'toto'

It work fine. What's wrong with *exec* ?

Thank you for your ideas

Comment: Not sure to understand your question, are you starting a `sudo find` from a script on the web server?

Comment: I'm sorry, I forgot to specify I use Php...
I just note I have zend_mm_heap corrupted in the log.
I use Zend Framework 1.9 on Php 5.2.16

Comment: what web server are you using? how is php configured for that server? (e.g. Apache module, fastcgi?)